# share an image in facebook via php

Tags: php, facebook

```
<?php
    $title=urlencode('Nature'); 
    $url=urlencode('http://trainees.ocs.org/training/hariharan/01-09-2014/facebook.php');
    $image=urlencode('http://trainees.ocs.org/training/hariharan/01-09-2014/images/img1.jpg');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sharing Images on Facebook</title>
<link href="css/facebook.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="all">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="img"><img src="images/img1.jpg" height="220" width="550" /></div>
    <div class="share"><a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=550,height=220');" href="javascript: void(0)">Share</a></div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is to share an image on facebook via php. but the image cannot display in my account. how to share an image on facebook using php?... please help me friends.

Comment: The Share dialog does not take any additional parameters besides the URL to share any more – all other information (title, description, image) will be taken from the Open Graph meta tags that the document under that URL contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code you need to share a link to Facebook using PHP. With small changes you can use this code to post just a message (without link), or to upload a photo in a Facebook album.

```
<?php
// require Facebook PHP SDK
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/
require_once("/YOUR_PATH_TO/facebook_php_sdk/facebook.php");

// initialize Facebook class using your own Facebook App credentials
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/#install
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$config['secret'] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$fb = new Facebook($config);

// define your POST parameters (replace with your own values)
$params = array(
  "access_token" => "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN", // see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
  "message" => "Here is a blog post about auto posting on Facebook using PHP #php #facebook",
  "link" => "http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php",
  "picture" => "http://i.imgur.com/lHkOsiH.png",
  "name" => "How to Auto Post on Facebook with PHP",
  "caption" => "www.pontikis.net",
  "description" => "Automatically post on Facebook with PHP using Facebook PHP SDK. How to create a Facebook app. Obtain and extend Facebook access tokens. Cron automation."
);

// post to Facebook
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
try {
  $ret = $fb->api('/YOUR_FACEBOOK_ID/feed', 'POST', $params);
  echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to first initialize facebook script like

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId        : your app Id
            channelUrl   : your site url //opional
            status       : true, // check login status (we don't make use of this)
            cookie       : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml        : true  // parse XFBML
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);           
    }(document));
</script>
```

Then in your page write in you document ready state

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#share_button').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                FB.ui(
                {
                    method: 'feed',
                    name: 'Your message',
                    link: 'your site url',
                    picture: '<?php echo $baseurl; ?>/your/image/url',
                    caption: 'Image caption',
                    description: '',
                    message: 'This is the information that you want to show people.'
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is share button

```
<div class="share">
    <a id="share_button" href=""><img src="images/fb_like.png" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

This works for me hope help you.

Comment: You need to create your app id in your facebook developer site you can follow this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/canvas or http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/how-to-create-facebook-application-to-get-an-app-id-for-your-website/

Comment: the image can be shared in fb, but the title cannot displayed. please tell me what i'm missing...

Comment: As I know the 'name' or 'caption' in FB.ui is your title. In my case name is my title an caption is my image name.  Hope if name is given then it/title should be there.